# Console/GUI surrogate application via Winapi

Tags: windows, winapi

Can someone with a good experience with WinAPI guide me in the right direction with app that behaves like this:

User starts an app (win32 with entry-point winmain). App connects to the database, selects data, does some internal calculation, if everything is good, launches a new app and exits. Blocking, possibly long action, but service-like, on success there is no GUI.

If there are problems (bad connection string, invalid data, etc.), the app creates a window with multiple controls and allows user to fix what he can.

If connection string and data is valid, but the application cannot be launched, previous window is not shown, but another one is created, with other set of controls, where user has to do other actions before he can continue.

So, what would be the cleanest way to handle such requirements.

So far I can imagine following approaches:

1) Create a message loop, and post a WM_CUSTOM_INIT, which causes initial data retrieval attempt, then, post back thread messages on different statuses.

2) Do everything as in console app, first, call database, then, if something goes wrong, create a message loop and window. Exit window, exit message loop, if nothing works, create another window and another message loop.

What bugs me is the hidden message loops the database app will create, because of CoInitialize(NULL). And PostThreadMessage, which might fail if some dll decides to throw a MessageBox indicating something. Also, in the first approach, I would be blocking on longer calls, which might lock some other app if it decides to enumerate windows or something with SendMessage/SendMessageTimeout(WM_GETTITLEORSOMETHING). Also the focus will probably be the problem in second case, as the app will loose the foreground privilege in the beginning, and then it wont be able to wake up as foreground again.

Overall this seems a bit messy, and the more I think about it, the more I feel I'm missing something, or doing something completely wrong.

Comment: What hidden message loop?  CoInitialize() doesn't create one, it creates an STA.  And dbase providers generally are not apartment threaded either.  If yours is then you *have* to create a message loop.

Comment: STA apartment has to pump messages, if there is no message loop, it creates an invisible one. At least that's how I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend CreateProcess:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can run your program:

- start
- do database-checks,
- if problems are detected create a GUI (CreateWindow()) or console (AllocConsole(), GetStdHandle(), Read/WriteConsole())
- if no problems occured call CreateProcess() and then exit immediately by calling ExitProcess()

There is no need to keep your program running while the called program runs.

Questions? -> Please comment.

Comment: I think I will loose foreground activation either way. If my app doesn't create a window at start, it looses the rights to display a window. Or doesn't?

Comment: Your first app could be a console app.  (Console apps can create GUIs as needed.)  The console app will keep the focus in the console window (unless the user clicks away).  If it then launches a good, I think you should still have foreground privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but it's too long:

Why is there no GUI on Success?  I don't mean to sound off, but I'm not following why would want your program to behave that way.

If you have a program that is not a console program, it's first job should be showing the user something, so they know it's running.  From there, if you have a job with long, blocking calls, it should be spun off into a separate thread.  Update the message loop thread with message passing, with a progress bar or log window, and keep the message loop running so what ever window you opened can respond to being moved/minimized/etc.

Then if there's a problem, your window is already there to use.  If there's not, pop up a message, wait a bit so it can be read by mortals (or ask them to click "OK"), then close.

A program using WinMain as its entry point that doesn't open a window on "successful" excecution is a poor design choice, in my opinon.  There is no indication to the user that the program even started, let along ran to completion, nor any indication of how long until it's finished.  You just double click the icon, and...nothing.

The only windows application that show zero UI that I've ever seen are Services, and you mentioned "service-like", but services are meant to keep running and provide a service once they're started.  They're not a once-and-done thing.  And they have their own message loops.

The "don't show anything on success" is a console paradigm.  And that could work here.  Just use main() (or wmain() for unicode) as your entry point, and start console interaction on problems.